# fs package not on client-side in nuxt

Tags: vue.js, filesystems, nuxt.js, fs, writefile

https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs/

I want to save my API data in JSON file

```js
const fs = require('fs');
if (fs.writeFileSync){
  fs.writeFileSync('home.txt', 'data') 
}
```

on page load, it works fine, but when I switch between page it's not work
`fs` showing empty

I want to store all my API data in folder to use as cache

please help to fix this, tried many packages to write files but all showed error with fs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fs` is a Node.js package, meaning that it will be used on the server, place where you **can** save something to the file system.

Meanwhile, after the initial request to a server, Nuxt is then hydrating into an SPA (since it's an isomorphic app), and during client side navigation you **don't have access** to backend API's (`fs`) anymore.

If you want to save some data from the client, you need to send it via HTTP to a backend.
You can maybe give a look to [`serverMiddleware`](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/configuration-glossary/configuration-servermiddleware#the-servermiddleware-property).

PS: Nuxt is not an MPA, like Wordpress so this is totally how Nuxt is supposed to work.

Comment: serverMiddleware running only first load. 

On first load `process.server` running and then `process.client`
`fs` not working in client side


I just want to create json file on every page load . please tell me if any alternative solution

Comment: @PirtaMatharu what for do you need a JSON file on every page load? What will it be used for? It's to mock some data?

Comment: I want to store all api response in json file to use as cache on next load (to reduce api call)

Comment: There are a lot of ways of optimizing for your use case. Your approach is not one of them. Try to google this one out with a pure client side approach rather than trying to use some server API methods here. For example, localStorage is a simple one. Apollo/SWR/Vuex memoization etc... could probably be helpful here if your website really needs to handle a lot of data and optimize it a lot.

Comment: I'm already using vuex. Thanks for your efforts